# Reading data from firebase real-time database using springboot

Tags: java, firebase, spring-boot, firebase-realtime-database

I am a newbie to cloud. I was trying to read some data from a couple of sensors stored in firebase's realtime database.

Here is the tree from realtime database:
[image]

1. How can I get realtime data in my Springboot (Java) application. An example or reference would be really helpful.
2. Is there a way I can auto dump my realtime database data to cloud firestore documents as soon as it is updated.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Spring. You can check some code examples here: https://medium.com/techwasti/spring-boot-firebase-crud-b0afab27b26e  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start

Answer (score 1):

Firebase has a set of Admin SDKs that are available for many server-side platforms, including Java. You'll want to include the SDK in your Springboot app, and then use the API as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start) to get the data from Firebase.

If you want to automatically create/update Firestore documents based on the data in the Realtime Database, have a look at [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions). They can be [triggered when a write happens to the Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events), and then update the relevant document(s).